# Laravel 8 with laravelcollective/html 6.2, Action Controller@function not defined

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and Stackoverflow

When Laravel7 is released, I started to learn Laravel.
The new version 8.0 was introduced not long ago and I started to try it.

I cannot define that the problem is caused by a newer version of Laravelor any misconfiguration.

When I try the following (edit.blade.php)

`{!! Form::open(['action' => ['ProductController@update', $product->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`

or

`{!! Form::open(['action' => [[ProductController::class, 'update'], $product->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`

an error occurred

**Action ProductController@update not defined**

then I tried to replace the controller name with a path like

`{!! Form::open(['action' => ['App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@update', $product->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`

or

`{!! Form::open(['action' => [[App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'update'], $product->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}`

**It works!**

so I think this is about namespace

but I have a namespace heading
`namespace App\Http\Controllers;` in my App\Http\ProductController.php

although I can solve the problem by typing the full path of the controller in the collective form,
I am worried that my code has configuration error or syntax errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a change to Laravel 8. There is no namespace prefix applied to your routes by default and there is no namespace prefix used when generating URLs to "actions".

To have the namespace prefixed to the Controller you are trying to reference when generating URLs to actions you would need to define the `$namespace` property on your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Now you can reference your action with that namespace prefix:

```
Form::open(['action' => ['ProductController@update', $product->id], 'method' => 'POST'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8: use this code I think your problem will be solved

web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('create', 'Product\ProductController@Create')->name('product.create')->middleware('can:Add Product');
    Route::post('create', 'Product\ProductController@Store')->name('product.store')->middleware('can:Add Product');
});
```

resources/views/product:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('product.store') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{-- START - PRODUCT INFORMATION --}}

    {{-- END- PRODUCT INFORMATION --}}
</form>
```

app/Http/Controllers/Products:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Products;

use App\Http\Requests\Product\ProductRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductController extends Controller {
    //---Constructor Function
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    }//---End of Function Constructor

    //---Create Product
    public function create() {
        return view('product.product_add');
    }//---End of Function create

    //---Store Product in Database
    public function store(ProductRequest $request) {
        //---Add Product Details in DB
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 : Collective form - This is using to create a Laravel view page

```
            {!! Form::open(['route' => '', 'id'=>'form','class' => 'needs-validation',]) !!}           
           
                <div class="form-group row">
                    {!! Form::label('employee_id', 'Employee ID:', ['class'=>'col-md-1 col-form-label  custom_required']) !!}
                         
                <!-- Employee ID -->
                <div class="form-group row">
                    {!! Form::label('employee_name', 'Employee Name:', ['class'=>'col-md-1 col-form-label  custom_required']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        {!! Form::text('employee_name', @$employee_id, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Employee Name', 'pattern'=> '^[a-z A-Z0-9_.-]*$']) !!}
                                   
                </div>     
                 <!-- Employee number -->
                 <div class="form-group row">
                    {!! Form::label('phone_number', 'Number:', ['class'=>'col-md-1 col-form-label  custom_required']) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        {!! Form::text('phone_number', @$phone_number, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required','placeholder' => 'number']) !!}
                     
                </div>    
                      
                {!! Form::close()  !!}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. It is more helpful if a short description/explanation is attached as to what is the answer trying to convey.

Comment: sure ranka47 defenetly next time clearly add the short explanation

Comment: This is my first post so i don't know ,i will be added next time clearly

Comment: [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) This would be helpful.